# Unsupported Grant Type Salesforce OAUTH2

Tags: vba, salesforce, authorization

I am using VBA to get authorization in Salesforce and then ultimately want to run a Salesforce report and dump the results in Excel. I have written the following to handle the authorization, but I am getting an unsupported_grant_type error. The code I have so far:

```
Dim XMLHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim username As String
Dim password As String
Dim PasswordnUsername As String
Dim argumentString As String

username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"

PasswordnUsername = password & ":" & username

argumentString = "?grant_type=password&" & _ 
                "client_id=abc123&" & _
                "client_secret=123abc&" & _
                "username=" & username & "&password=" & password
MsgBox (argumentString)

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
XMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://mysalesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", False

XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "basic " + Base64Encode(PasswordnUsername)

XMLHTTP.send (argumentString)

MsgBox (XMLHTTP.responseText)
```

When I print XMLHTTP.responseText, this is where the unsupported_grant_type is reported.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

T

Comment: Try deleting the first `?` at the start of your `argumentString`, then send the request and see if you get a different error message. So: `argumentString = "grant_type=password&" & _ "client_id=abc123&" & _ "client_secret=123abc&" & _ "username=" & username & "&password=" & password`. Also, you may need to URL encode the arguments in your `argumentString` if they contain non-URL-safe characters.

Comment: Thank you chillin. Removing the ? did the trick. I never thought it would be that simple. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using ["Username-password flow"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5). All params in the URL, without displaying a popup letting user type his credentials straight to SF (ideally if there's user interaction rather than backend systems talking to each other you're supposed to use [another OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm) so your app doesn't handle passwords, can't leak them).

Troubleshooting:

1. Make sure `username` in your request is encoded. At very least put `%40` instead of `@`. If your attempt doesn't even show up in user's login history - wrong / incorrectly encoded username.
2. You might need the security token also silently appended to the password (again, look into user's login history, maybe there's "Failed: API security token required").
3. If you use Setup -> My Domain feature, check whether you're allowed to log in from generic `login.salesforce.com`. Maybe your organisation disabled it and allows only the branded login domain (will impact API access too). Or maybe your admins allow logging in only from certain IPs...
4. Also you don't need to add `Authorization: Basic` + username & pass in this call, you pass it in POST's payload and that's enough.

If you have Postman, curl, SoapUI or any client like that - might help before jumping straight to VBA?

This works for me (with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header)

[image: Sample Postman request (censored)]

Comment: Hi, do you happen to know how to do this exact same thing without username and password?

Comment: Hi @JPG, maybe post a new question with what you need and we'll see what makes sense. You can have completely anonymous access by making a Visualforce page, exposing it on "Site" and unauthenticated people can access it, pass parameters. Watch for hackers and spamers though. SF has lots of login flows: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5. Maybe you can display SF login page and it'll come back to your app with session id (you don't see password, just success), like https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820476/313628

Comment: Maybe you can preauthorise users in SF (make "connected app" with certificate and specify which profiles are ok to use it), then your app needs to pass only username and sign the request with certificate (trust by certs exchanged offline, not by passwords). For this check out the JWT flow https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5. This is pretty cool walkthrough: https://gist.github.com/booleangate/30d345ecf0617db0ea19c54c7a44d06f

Comment: Mate @eyescream i just had a chat about what you said with some coworkers that said the same thing about the hackers or spammers. I believe what i'm trying to achieve is quite simple and has been done before. This is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63254838/insufficient-privileges-when-trying-to-display-user-photos-on-external-sites thanks in advance