# Can not connect to salesforce api

Tags: salesforce

A client of ours gave us this api : 
https://xxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/fetchProjectDetails

Along with this I have the following from the client
Username , Password, Security Token, Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

Using https://apitester.com/ I get a CORS error but I'm not sure if that is the issue as I'm sending a POST request.

I don't have any experience using the Salesforce API and am unable to use the API.

Any help would be appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 API calls, one to log in

- get the final server's address (because load balancer may send you somewhere else to fire subsequent requests against)
- and most importantly to get valid session id.

And then you can run your actual API call.

How is this supposed to run? As a background system integration (with dedicated SF user each time & you need to store credentials) or will you display to people the SF login page, they put their own credentials in (your app doesn't see them, just sees the final session id as result). Pick right OAuth2 flow for the job...

If it's system integration [Unsupported Grant Type Salesforce OAUTH2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53558262/313628) can help you start.

There will be more magic to it ideally (plan your code to reuse session ids, don't login every time; if session expires fail gracefully, issue new login call. If that login dies because password expired for example - notify SF team somehow... and bonus points if you make your actual processing code independent from the login method so there's hope to eventually let people log in with their own SF credentials...)

After you got session id you can call your service (ideally it'd be `instance_url` from response + `/services/apexrest/fetchProjectDetails`. You just pass the session id as HTTP `Authorization` header with value = `Bearer sessionidgoeshere`.

This service was custom made by your client so we can't help you more without seeing source code. What HTTP action will it be (GET, POST...), what parameters - contact your client. This self-paced training might give you some idea: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yeah I've emailed the client to send us details or preferably source code access.