# Insufficient Privileges when trying to display user photos on external sites

Tags: api, salesforce, token, external

I have this situation. Im trying to display user photos from an external site, all the configurations about remote sites are already set. I created a connected app in org A and from org B i'm retrieving the users from org A.

All of this works however i cannot show the photos from those users because for that to happen i have to be able to use the ConnectApi.UserProfiles.GetPhoto method which i'm doing right now but i keep getting the "insufficient privileges" error.  I tried getting the AccessToken through postman like this
[image]

This redirects me to the login site so i can log into my org with my credentials. After that i get an AccessToken.

Next up, i want to be able to get the photos from users from the external site with the AccessToken, However i'm still getting the same error message "Insufficient Priviledges". Am i missing something? thanks in advance

According to: https://sforcenotes.blogspot.com/2015/10/solution-to-display-salesforce-user.html?showComment=1596211057195#c5848226245946017759
The solution is fairly easy but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm bit lost. You have some app that wants to log in to Salesforce and pull images from it? Or do you want to call out from Salesforce and pull images from external app? For first one you likely need "connected app". But you need "remote site settings" or "named credentials" only for calling out.

I'm assuming it's option 1.

There are lots of ways to log in to SF, SOAP API (just username + password), REST API (lots of OAuth2 options, with username+pass or username + JWT or just OAuth2 client id and user logs in to SF interactively, you don't see the password)... Sounds like you're past this stage?

A successful login response will look bit like that (depends on method used):

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Dx0000000BV7z/005x00000012Q9P",
"issued_at":"1278448832702",
"instance_url":"https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/",
"signature":"0CmxinZir53Yex7nE0TD+zMpvIWYGb/bdJh6XfOH6EQ=",
"access_token":"00Dx0000000BV7z!AR8AQAxo9UfVkh8AlV0Gomt9Czx9LjHnSSpwBMmbRcgKFmxOtvxjTrKW19ye6PE3Ds1eQz3z8jr3W7_VbWmEu4Q8TVGSTHxs",
"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

You're supposed to take from it the `access_token` (that's your session id. It'll always start with org's id, compare with Setup -> Company information) and `instance_url` (that's where you're supposed to send any subsequent requests. No more calling the login gateways: login.salesforce.com, test.salesforce.com or mydomain.my.salesforce.com). If you're getting "Insufficient Privileges" I think you didn't change the endpoint.

You can test you logged in OK by sending a `GET` to the `id` endpoint you received. It'll give you OpenId info about your user.

Here's my GET to fetch OpenId data with the "Authorization: Bearer " request

[image]

So another GET with same header and I have my ugly mug:

[image]

If you want somebody else's picture - query similar to `/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT SmallPhotoUrl, FullPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id = '005...'` should work. Check [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) fields.

```
{
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "User",
      "url" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/User/(redacted)"
    },
    "SmallPhotoUrl" : "https://(redacted)/profilephoto/7293L0000008Tfq/T",
    "FullPhotoUrl" : "https://(redacted)/profilephoto/7293L0000008Tfq/F"
  } ]
}
```

The key thing is to use the new endpoint and pass the session id in the header. You might even find it easier to use [Chatter API to pull photos](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_UserPhotos.htm) (also REST-based)

Comment: Yes as you said i have a connected app. I'm in an organization and im trying to retrieve users from another org.  Yes i got a response very similar to what you got and i got the access token. I'm using the connectApi.UserProfiles.getPhoto method to be able to do this and this is were i keep getting the insufficient priviledges error. I'll try to get it as you pointed out.

Comment: Aren't "ConnectApi" classes for accessing data from same org, not another org? So you can build your own UI for Chatter if you want? You might be getting insuf. privileges because user/file with this ID doesn't exist in this org. Ditch them or use connectapi all right but in the org FROM which you want to pull photos, expose some custom `@RestResource, @HttpGet` class & then call them from the other org? Might be better performance rather than lots of network round trips

Comment: right, i already have the users from the other organization through a query. The problem that i have is exclusively with the getPhoto method from the ConnectApi.UserProfiles class. That might work, will try it.